# How do I implement an interface without a default implementation in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, interface

I'm coming to Objective-C from ECMAScript like languages, so this is probably the wrong question, but I can't determine how else to ask it:

I have an interface defined in a header file. I don't want to implement it directly, I just want classes to use it.

```
So say: Car.h is implemented by Telsa.m, Mercedes.m, Peugeot.m, etc.
```

*Is this possible?* I have no use for a default implementation of "car", but I want to make sure each of the brands implements the interface so I can pass any "Car" around reliably. I don't want it to be possible to instance a Car.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In objective-c when you want to write a class you have to specify the class interface (@interface usually in .h file) and the class implmentation (.m file)

When you want to define an interface that any other class can implement in objective-c thats called a protocol.

```
@protocol XYZPieChartViewDataSource
- (NSUInteger)numberOfSegments;
- (CGFloat)sizeOfSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segmentIndex;
@optional
- (NSString *)titleForSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segmentIndex;
- (BOOL)shouldExplodeSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segmentIndex;
@required
- (UIColor *)colorForSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segmentIndex;
@end
```

Therefore you can write a class that implements this protocol, in order to do this first you have to declare that your class implements this protocol (.h file).

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject <XYZPieChartViewDataSource>
...
@end
```

After that you have to write the methods that you want to implement, you must write the required ones and you can write if you need to the optional ones

```
- (BOOL)shouldExplodeSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segmentIndex {
// do someting
}

- (UIColor *)colorForSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segmentIndex {
// do someting 
}
```

As they pointed out you can take a look to the protocol docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html

Comment: Giving it to you since you put the relevant code in here as well.

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is a *protocol*, defined in Objective-C using `@protocol`. These are, perhaps confusingly, the equivalent of Java-style interfaces. You can define a class to implement any number of protocols, and there is no default implementation required. Read Apple's [Working with Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html) for the details.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I awarded it to the answer with example code, but I appreciate the speed. I was able to do what I wanted with a Protocol. Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

To use a protocol for that is a good pattern, because it is very flexible. But looking to your classes `Tesla` … it seems to be that way, that these are subclasses of a base class `Car`.

In such cases it might be more convenient for the implementation to make `Car` a partial abstract base class. That means that `Car`

- declares the API as you want
- partially implements the API
- is never instantiated

The advantage is that you have to implement methods equal in every subclass in the base class. So it shortens the *implementation*.

Of course, you can combine that:

```
@interface Car : NSObject <CarProtocol>
…
@end

@implementation Car
// Define methods that are common for all subclasses of Car
// Define methods included in CarProtocol, but not definable in a base class empty. 
…
@end

@interface Tesla : Car // Protocol is inherited
…
@end

@implementation Tesla
// Override methods that needs a special behavior for this subclass
// Override methods that are not definable at the base class
// Add method definitions that are special to Tesla (i. e. Power plug)
…
@end

@interface AmphibiousCraft : NSObject<CarProtocol, ShipProtocol> // Implementation of Car is no real help
…
@end

@implementation AmphibiousCraft
…
@end
```

Comment: From what I've been reading, since Objective-C doesn't formally support abstract classes, that Protocols make more sense in this scenario?

Comment: As mentioned you can combine that: To define the public API, use formal protocols (`@protocol`). To implement them use abstract base classes to reduce code repetitions. Otherwise you will finde yourself writing the same code again and again in `Tesla`, `Mercedes`, `Peugeot` and so on.